# GBA programming with Visual HAM in C

Tags: c, makefile, game-boy-advance

I am interested in programming for the Game Boy Advance using the Visual HAM IDE in C. However, every time I build a project I get a message stating:

```
'make.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I downloaded GnuWin32 and make. Then, inside the ham visual editor I clicked advanced, options and set the directory of the MAKE_MODE (I guess some kind of environment variable) to the directory where the make program is.

Any suggestions on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Reinstall the hole vham package to the desired destination from the get-go. You can find it here: www.jharbour.com/gba/ham-280-full-win32.zip

You can't move the folders around. Even if you change the PATH variables this problem will persist.

Answer (score -1):

Find where on your system the make program is in. Probably in cygwin's /usr/bin. Add that path to your system dos path.

Windows with cygwin is a screwed up hybrid system. You probably have three paths going on at once. You have the cygwin one. If you open a cygwin shell and type make I bet it finds the make program. Then if you open a dos shell ( in accessories/command prompts ) I bet it won't find the make program.

You will need to add it. Every version of windows does this differently but it is generally under right click on my computer/properties/advanced/environment variables. You will need to add it there.

And finnally there is the path known to your ide (probably). I don't know HAM, but it looks like you already did whatever they told you.

When you are done you should be able to invoke "make" from the windows/dos command prompt.

Comment: I am not using Cygwin, I installed GnuWin32